# Cannot find module logo.svg?inline - Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, svg

Using package: [vue-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-loader).

Created `svg.d.ts` file with the following contents:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any
  export default content
}
```

Then using in a component this way:

```js
import register from '@/assets/svg/register.svg?inline'
```

Causes an error: `Typescript Cannot find module '@/assets/svg/register.svg?inline'`

But if i remove `?inline` it stops complaining. How to correctly declare svg module in `.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

`vue-svg-loader` does not support an `inline` option, so that query string would be considered part of the module path, leading to the `Cannot find module` error.

As you discovered, removing the option resolves the error. You've already properly declared the `svg` module type definition, so nothing else needs to be done.